# transitionstart event in React component

Tags: reactjs, events

I am trying to add a callback function in my React component to capture the transitionstart event. Apparently, only transitionend is supported. Do you know any workaround?

```
<div
    className="super-component--animated"
    { /** Not supported **/ }
    onTransitionStart={() => {
        this.changeAnimationStatus(true);
    }}
    onTransitionEnd={() => {
        this.changeAnimationStatus(false);
    }}
>
     Hello Friends!
</div>
```

Transition events: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionstart_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All unsupported event in React should be handled vanilla style.

```
const MyComp = () => {
...
 const handler = () => {
 ref.current.addEventListener('your_event', () => {...})
 }
 return <div ref={ref}/>
}
```

see the following sandbox:
[transition start listener example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-mestorf-lod8u)

Answer (score 0):

In modern React, [as explained in the documentation](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#subscribing-to-events), you will want to use the `useEffect` hook and ensure that you remove the event listener when the component is unmounted:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll(e) {
      console.log('Transition started');
    }

    window.addEventListener('transitionstart', handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('transitionstart', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return <div>My component</div>;
});
```

This will ensure that you component doesn't subscribe to the event multiple times and that you cleanup when it's removed from the page.